# Multi tenant azure app not visible for other tenants

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

**Summary: How do I make a multi tenant app available to other Azure AD tenants?**

**Details:**
I am writing a C# ASP.NET library using which I want to create subscriptions and register for change notifications. 
I am using Microsoft Graph API v1.0 for this operation.

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) documentation to obtain the access token for a service account. 
The first step listed in the documentation requires us to register the app on [Azure AD Portal](https://portal.azure.com/#home)

Since I am building this app for multiple customers, I want this to be a multi tenant app. I followed this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-registration-to-be-multi-tenant) to register a multi tenant application, but I have a query as to how to make this app discover-able by other tenants ?

Do I need to publish it to be able to achieve this? If yes, can anyone please direct me towards any article which tells how to do that ?

Comment: No, you don't. For a multi-tenant application, the initial registration for the application lives in the Azure AD tenant used by the developer. When a user from a different tenant signs in to the application for the first time, Azure AD asks them to consent to the permissions requested by the application. If they consent, then a representation of the application called a service principal is created in the user’s tenant.

Comment: Thank you for replying @CaiyiJu. In my case, since it's a one time thing, I want the admins of other tenants to grant the consent to the app, from the Azure portal itself. But so far, I have not been able to see this app when I login as some tenant other than the one with which the app was created.

Comment: Do you mean under Enterprise applications blade of any tenant or the one where it was created ?
Basically, the idea in my head is, the other tenant should be able to see this app somewhere (marketplace or enterprise applications) and then navigate to authorization sub-tab inside the app and grant admin consent to the app for all the users of his domain. Will this be possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need to publish it to be able to achieve this?

No, you don't. For a multi-tenant application, the initial registration for the application lives in the Azure AD tenant used by the developer. When a user from a different tenant signs in to the application for the first time, Azure AD asks them to consent to the permissions requested by the application. **If they consent, then a representation of the application called a service principal is created in the user’s tenant**.

> Do you mean under Enterprise applications blade of any tenant or the
>   one where it was created ?

It will exist in any tenant once a user from that tenant signs in to the application.

Comment: This app will execute in the background independent of user interaction every few hours. As a result, the users will not be able to grant consent to this app from the portal. Is there any other way to obtain admin consent ?

Comment: @SwastiGupta The user must sign in to the application for the first time, then the app will exist under enterprise applicaitons(in the tenant which the user belongs to). If this user is not an admin, you need to let the admin login in to the application and grant admin consent. Or let the admin login in Azure portal and find the application under enterprise applications to grant admin consent. After the admin consent, other users can login in directly. We can only obtain admin consent with the interactive way.

Comment: Guys, do you know about any good howto example to reach this goal? thanks

Comment: @Alberto, can you explain a little more about what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to create an azure app which Id/secret could be used on different tenants, from different companies. I tried the "multitenant" azure app option, but It could not authenticate into another sp tenant, even though it was registered into appinv.aspx

Comment: @TonyJu can you please elaborate more on `Or let the admin login in Azure portal and find the application under enterprise applications to grant admin consent.` As a tenant admin I tried finding app under enterprise applications which is registered as multi-tenant in another tenant, but I couldn't. For now as a workaround, I signed in via URL created manually for that background service app.